# How to properly write a dockerfile to run an init script and then the python app

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image for our software, before running the app I need to run an initialization script. I tried a combination of ENTRYPOINT, CMD and exec "$@" in the init script.

Last lines from dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint.sh
CMD ['python', './myapp.py', '-arg1', '-arg2']
```

Example from entrypoint.sh

```
echo "write something"
...
exec "$@"
```

When I run the docker I'd expect the entrypoint to run, do all the operations written in there, and then run the CMD. The entrypoint executes but the app doesn't start and the docker closes itself.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong however I searched for solutions and suggestions but I didn't find any. Do you have any suggestions or can you point me on the right direction?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) ?

Comment: RUN is not viable as I need it runtime and not on build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the exec form for the ENTRYPOINT as well, and also you should use double quotes, not single.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["python", "./myapp.py", "-arg1", "-arg2"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai , it actually works now! Just a little issue, when I run the image with the usual `docker run myimage` when I hit CTRL+C it doesn't stop the container itself even if it returns me on my shell prompt. I guess I need to add the `STOPSIGNAL SIGKILL` in my `dockerfile`. Is it the proper way? Thanks again!

Comment: Depends what your program does and how you run the container. The rule is: the container will stay active as long as there is a running process inside it. So you could investigate the container and see what is still running once your program stops. I don't think you need to play around with STOPSIGNAL for now, the problem is much more simple.

Comment: thanks again for your help. Indeed, after the initialization my python app became PID 1 and it looks like as PID 1 it ignores SIGINT however if I run a `docker stop` it stops the container properly, I mean, it doesn't wait 10 second and force a SIGKILL, it stops it in a matter of couple of seconds. Reading around I guess I need to wrap my python app with a shell script which capture the SIGINT/CTRL+C signal.